# Is it possible to use !(not) in JS switch statement?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, logical-operators

Actually, I was working with the JS switch statement. I used (!) in a switch statement, but it is not working. here's my code

```js
function showResult(){
  let firstNum = document.getElementById("num1").value;
  firstNum = Number(firstNum);
  let secNum = document.getElementById("num2").value;
  secNum = Number(secNum);
  let operator = document.getElementById("operator").value;
  let getErrorElem = document.getElementById("error");
  let getResElem = document.getElementById("res");
  let result;
  // alert(typeof(operator));

  switch(operator){
      case null:
      case "":
          getErrorElem.innerHTML = "Operatot field can't be empty";
          break;
  }

  switch(!(operator)){
      case "+":
      case "-":
      case "/":
      case "*":
          alert("You can only input (+, -, *, /) these signs in operator field");
          break;
  }
}
```

I got three values from the user, the first number, the second number and the operator in the operator field I only want (+,-,*,/) these values, except these values there's an error message. I used a switch statement to validate this field, but not working. If I use (if) statement it is working properly. Please explain that how can I validate this field with switch statement using ! operator.

Comment: What do you expect to happen with `!"+"`, `!"-"`, `!"/"` or `!"*"`? o.O

Comment: That's not how switch works - that checks if `!(operator)` (which is always false except when operator is an empty string) is equal to one of "+", "-", "/", or "*"

Comment: `if (!["+", "-", "*", "/"].includes(operator)) { ... }`

Comment: You dont need two switch statements, you can handle all cases in one switch. I think you should read up more on how switch works.

Comment: Simply add a [default case](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) to your switch statement

Comment: actually, I just want to know that we can use ! operator in switch statement or not.

Comment: You have the code, so you could test it? Just add the missing default cases to your current switch statements and see what happens (spoiler it works with not operator but i'd advice against it).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My simple question is that, can we use the (!) operator in the JS switch statement or not. If yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need something like this:

```js
function showResult(){
  let firstNum = document.getElementById("num1").value;
  firstNum = Number(firstNum);
  let secNum = document.getElementById("num2").value;
  secNum = Number(secNum);
  let operator = document.getElementById("operator").value;
  let getErrorElem = document.getElementById("error");
  let getResElem = document.getElementById("res");
  let result;
  // alert(typeof(operator));

  switch(operator){
      case null:
      case "":
          getErrorElem.innerHTML = "Operatot field can't be empty";
          break;

      case "+":
      case "-":
      case "/":
      case "*":
          // Handle the right input.
          break;

      default:
          alert("You can only input (+, -, *, /) these signs in operator field");
          break;
  }
}
```